# Selenium Webdriver - Wait until user clicks button without ID

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, xpath, isenabled

I am using Selenium Webdriver with an Excel VBA automatization in Chrome and I am having some trouble when waiting until users clics a button.

The web's code is the following:

[image: web code]

I have tried with FindElementByCss, FindElementByID..., also with IsPresent, IsEnabled... but nothing worked. Mi code right now is the following:

```
t = Timer
    Do While bot.FindElementById("ui-button-text").IsPresent = True
        bot.Wait 500
        If Timer - t = 10 Then Exit Do 'Para evitar bucle infinito
    Loop
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is only one id, and there are multiple classes. When viewed in html, there is no setting for id. There is a possibility that there are multiple when viewed as a class. You have to check which order you are looking for among several.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the HTML:

[image: 66044675]

**`ui-button-text`** is the value of the `class` attribute, but not of the **`id`** attribute and there are multiple `<span>` elements with `class` attribute value as **`ui-button-text`** with different *textContent*.

---

To validate the **presence** of the elements you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Element with text as **Cancelar**:

  - Using *xpath*:

    ```
    Do While bot.FindElementByXPath("//span[@class='ui-button-text' and text()='Cancelar']").IsPresent = True
    ```
- Element with text as **Repetir**:

  - Using *xpath*:

    ```
    Do While bot.FindElementByXPath("//span[@class='ui-button-text' and text()='Repetir']").IsPresent = True
    ```
- Element with text as **Aceptar**:

  - Using *xpath*:

    ```
    Do While bot.FindElementByXPath("//span[@class='ui-button-text' and text()='Aceptar']").IsPresent = True
    ```

---

To validate the if the elements are **enabled**, you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Element with text as **Cancelar**:

  - Using *xpath*:

    ```
    Do While bot.FindElementByXPath("//span[@class='ui-button-text' and text()='Cancelar']").IsEnabled = True
    ```
- Element with text as **Repetir**:

  - Using *xpath*:

    ```
    Do While bot.FindElementByXPath("//span[@class='ui-button-text' and text()='Repetir']").IsEnabled = True
    ```
- Element with text as **Aceptar**:

  - Using *xpath*:

    ```
    Do While bot.FindElementByXPath("//span[@class='ui-button-text' and text()='Aceptar']").IsEnabled = True
    ```